# PHP Database - Output total revenue by multiplying two values

Tags: php, mysql, database

Alright so I have a website, **paynite.com**
which uses a PHP script. I'd like to show the total revenue by each user.

So the user's are defined by the ID: usern
and this ID exists in the table: Users

REF: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VA9Zl.png

I have products that are sold on my site in the table called: items
and I want the row's "sales" and "price_extended" to multiple to form $revenue in the code only when the author ID and the usern matches

Author is defined by the ID: author
and this ID exists in the table: items

REF: https://i.gyazo.com/34dc923c79263c1ec7a0918f7741e4ac.png

How can I do this? I've been stuck on this for like 4 hours :( I have very little coding knowledge lmao.

The code I tried to use outputs the total revenue vs sales across the whole site..

```
<div class="center aligned column dashboard-product-info-box">
    <div class="ui statistic">
        <div class="value dashboard-product-info-value" id="dashboard_product_revenue_value">
            <?php $revenue = 0; $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sellify_items ORDER BY id"); if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>0) { while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { $revenue = $row['sales'] * $row['price_extended']; } } echo (number_format($revenue)); ?></div>
<div class="label dashboard-product-info-title">Revenue</div>
    </div>
```

***Help would greatly be appriciated :)***

Comment: `mysql_query` is _deprecated_ [read ***the red warning box***](http://php.net/mysql_connect). Switch to `PDO` or `mysqli` instead (the `i` is for _improved_). Also: mixing markup with DB queries is really not the way to go. Lastly: Look into joining tables, and grouping the results. Also know that you can `SELECT field1*field2` or `SELECT SUM(field1)`, grouped by ID, that can be a powerful tool at your disposal, don't you think?

Comment: tbh im so lost right now just need to find a way to take the session username and match it with the author name from the items table and then it'll output the sales * price total for all items that match the author name

Comment: please put the structure of the tables that have the fields that you want, for  construct the query!

Comment: You *have very little coding knowledge lmao* (sic) and you're building a user-account based, ecommerce marketplace platform using deprecated PHP code... have I understood that correctly?

Comment: ^^ yea. I got it tho just made new rows in the users table and made it so that when the payment goes through it'll update those tables hue